# How to configure the layout so that the output will be output on the listview below the input search

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I have created a design with the following source axml:
when the listview output is shown getting data from the sqllite database the listview will overlap the test textview,edittext as below:

[image]

Required Output Result Listview should be below as shown below:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/test"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="87.5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/test_input"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="152.0dp"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/test" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="128.5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ButtonClick"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/test_input" />
    <ListView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listtable"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/MyButton" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You want it to be in center ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the Appcompat Library i would do the following changes to your layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/LinearContent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:text="Test"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="87.5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/test_input"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="152.0dp"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/test" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="128.5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Search"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/test_input" />
</android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
<android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@id/LinearContent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listtable"
        />
   </android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Revert in case it doesn't work

Comment: no i want the listview to be below the row containing the textview,textedit and button.Currently the output from the listview overlaps the button,textview and textedit instead of below of them.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
Change the properties of list view with the following:
android:layout_alignBottom to
android:layout_below

Comment: I answered this you should've marked my answer as right!!